# Font Awesome icon missing from Edge print preview

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm using a Font Awesome tick icon for styled radio buttons which seems to work in all popular browsers including MS Edge except when printed, the icon shows in all print previews except in Edge print preview.

The icon is set in the css:

```
content: "\f00c";
```

A jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kvo8e55w/)

Comment: This fiddle works just fine for me in MS Edge Print Preview. However, I noticed that it took some time (about 15 seconds) for them to appear, as if Edge renders page and loads font in print preview slower than usual. May be try cleaning cache/resetting Edge settings?..

Answer (score 0):

There is a known [compatibility issue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting#internet-explorer-compatibility-mode);

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

add this meta tag as the **first** tag in your `<head>`.

Comment: I believe the printing of the jsfiddle is actually working with or without this meta tag, according to keaukraine above and one other (sorry I hadn't realised that before), but it's not working as part of my larger system, so some other css in the system must be causing it not to print. It will take me a while to trace why.